# How do I find the index of a json object in an array based off of a value of its properties

Tags: redisjson

I am fairly new to Redis and RedisJson and I have been through all the documentation I can get my hands on, but I still can't seem to figure this one out. I am hoping someone could shed some light on this situation to help me understand. My end goal is to be able to remove the JSON object from the responses array using JSON.ARRPOP. I need to get the index of the object first and I can't seem to do that.

Here is my object structure:

```
JSON.SET test:1 $ '{ "responses":[{"responseId":"29aab59c-10b0-48c0-ab91-8873fb6e2238"},{"responseId":"ab79f09b-8e31-41f4-9191-ef89a34964d3"}]}'
```

Check the path:

```
JSON.GET test:1 $.responses[*].responseId
```

RETURNS:

> "["29aab59c-10b0-48c0-ab91-8873fb6e2238","ab79f09b-8e31-41f4-9191-ef89a34964d3"]"

Ok looks good I have an array of two strings lets get that index of 29aab59c-10b0-48c0-ab91-8873fb6e2238.

```
JSON.ARRINDEX test:1 $.responses[*].responseId '"29aab59c-10b0-48c0-ab91-8873fb6e2238"'
```

RETURNS:

1. (nil)
2. (nil)

It appears to have searched but found nothing?
At first I thought it was an escape character issue but I get the same results with responeIds as integers 1 and 2.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JSON.ARRINDEX can only search for scalar values. Objects and arrays are not scalars so you can't search for them.

For your use case you should look at https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/indexing_json/